# Selenium with Java and Eclipse and SmartGWT

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, smartgwt

first time here and I tried to search for this info, so please forgive if this has been asked before. I am fairly knew to coding/selenium. I don't seem to have an issue with anything other than our SmartGWT screens and wondering if anybody could help with suggestions...I can't seem to get Selenium to work at all withing anything SmartGWT related actually

For example I have a date field and I want to type in a new date

This is the code according to firepath

```
    <input id="isc_B" class="selectItemText" type="TEXT" tabindex="1131"    
    style="width:66px;height:12px;-moz-user-focus:normal;" 
    autocomplete="OFF" onselect="if (window.isc_ComboBoxItem_0 == null) 
    return;isc_ComboBoxItem_0.$54h()"
    oninput="isc_ComboBoxItem_0._handleInput()" spellcheck="true"
    $377="$378" $376="isc_ComboBoxItem_0" handlenativeevents="false" 
    name="valueField"/>
```

According to firepath these are the xpaths for it

```
    [.//*[@id='isc_B']

    html/body/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div/form/table/tbody[2]/tr[2]/td[1]/input
```

and I've tried these:

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='isc_B']")).sendKeys...;
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='isc_B']")).sendKeys...;
    driver.findElement(By.id("isc_B")).sendKeys...;
```

and can't get anything to recognize. any pointers would be awesome and thank you in advance. Do I need to import specific libraries for smartGWT or something?

Answer (score 0):

Don't go by the XPaths suggested by FirePath..Try to create relative XPaths..Because absolute XPATHs can change..
For the above input tag I would recommend you use something like below

```
driver.findElement(By.className("selectItemText")).sendKeys("yourDate");
```

EDIT: Based on your website below is the code which works absolutely fine for me:

```
WebDriver driver=WebDriverFactory.getBrowser("http://www.tobymob.com/test/test.html");
        driver.findElement(By.className("selectItemText")).sendKeys("someDate");
```

Comment: Thanks...yeah I tried that one too... Sorry I had trouble posting..it wouldn't let me put all the combinations I tried. I tried classname, combos of CSS, long xpath...and nothing works. That's why I thought there must be some other setup in eclipse I need to do? Non-gwt items work fine

Comment: do you have a public URL to replicate that issue?

Comment: No, I wish. It's private (company) software. Thank you so much for trying to help. If you come up with any other ideas let me know

Comment: okay I have the code here (I think) top left is the date field if you can find anything that would be awesome... www.tobymob.com/test/test.html

Comment: check the edited answer..I've tried on above url which you've mentioned and its working

Comment: interesting, stripped out on that test url like that, you are correct, it certainly does work. As soon as I try it in our software it doesn't? "no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"selectItemText"}". Well at least now I know my code works. not sure where to go from here, but thanks again for your help

Comment: is there an issue of waiting..try to apply selenium waits(implicit / explicit / fluent waits) or manual wait using Thread.Sleep(timeInMilliSeconds)

Comment: yeah that was my first thought. I put a 5 minute wait even just to make sure and no go. I don't know if its a permission thing (even though the first thing I am doing is logging in) or what is going on

Comment: this is GWT sample website see if you can replicate same issue here: http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCheckBox